# Nginx - how to change request header Referer

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

new to NGINX. 
Currently running a local reverse proxy using Nginx.

Just wondering how I can change the Referer in the request header from http://localhost:8080 to say a different server_name like me.example.com

Finding it difficult to find clear documentation on this subject.
have tried setting this value using:

```
proxy_set_header Referer "me.example.com";
```

Doesn't seem to do anything.

Any help on this greatly appreciated.

```
server {
  listen       8080;
  server_name  localhost;

   # test APi
  location /test/api {
    # Edit this line only:
    proxy_pass https://test.com/test/api;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    break;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4567;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Referer "me.example.com";
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your nginx configuration.

Comment: added nginx config

Answer (score 3):

The `proxy_set_header` directive sends headers to the backend. If you want nginx to return headers to the client, then the `add_header` directive is what you're looking for.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header

Comment: Thanks for the reply @EstebanGarcia, tried adding with no success: 



add_header Referer "http://me.example.com"

Comment: replaced proxy_set_header Referer "me.example.com"

with 

add_header Referer "http://me.example.com"

Comment: it will respond with a json object

Comment: But what is HTTP Status code returned? As you can see in the documentation I sent you, the add_header will only add the header if the status code are `equals 200, 201 (1.3.10), 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, 307 (1.1.16, 1.0.13), or 308 (1.13.0)`. And `If the always parameter is specified (1.7.5), the header field will be added regardless of the response code.`

Comment: There is no point in returning `Referer` header to the browser, the header is only useful in requests.